# When I try pause and play in jsFiddle, my code works but it doesn't work in my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a code online to pause and play a timer. When I used it in [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zrNV5/58/), it worked but when I copied the same code into my html page, it didn't work? Can anyone explain why did this happen?

The code in my HTML :

```
<body onload="start();">
<script>
function start() {
var output = $('h1');
var isPaused = false;
var time = 30;
var t = window.setInterval(function() {
    if(!isPaused) {
        time--;
        output.text("0:" +time);
    }
}, 1000);
}
//with jquery
$('.pause').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isPaused = true;
});

$('.play').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isPaused = false;
});

</script>
<a href="#" class="play">Play</a>
<a href="#" class="pause">Pause</a>
<h1>0</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: add jquery to your page.

Comment: Have to added the specified **Jquery  2.0.2** in your page?

Comment: No, I didn't add anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsFiddle inserts the `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` tag automatically.

Here, you must do it yourself.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

---

### This is optional:

Pro Tip: Use a **CDN** (**C**ontent **D**elivery **N**etwork). They have thoroughly optimized delivery, and will often:

**I)**   Send the content from the server physically closest to the end user. This leads to faster load speeds.

**II)**  Caching in the browser. This means that if the site **www.example.com** already uses the script you want, it never gets loaded again (until the cache is cleared). The old copy is used, and this means no loading time for the script.

**In conclusion**: Use a CDN! They're often free! Why not?